# I am having a container which is flex and justified centre and aligned centre. when I create another flex item inside it space-between does not work

Tags: html, css, flexbox

1. A container with flex and centered horizontally and vertically
2. I create two divs which are placed column wise
3. Now I have a third div which is given a flex with a row and needs to be displayed space between but space between does not work
   here is the code

```
<style>
      
       .flex{
           width: 100vw;
           height: 100vh;
           border: 1px solid black;
           display: flex;
           flex-direction: column;
           align-items: center;
           justify-content: center;

       }
       .flex1,.flex2{
           width: 300px;
           border: 1px solid black;
       }
       .flex3{
           display: flex;
           justify-content: space-between;
       }
      
    </style>
<body>
    <div class="flex">
        <div class="flex1">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae alias dolorum cum sunt necessitatibus facere eveniet corrupti fugit fuga excepturi.</div>
        <div class="flex2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Commodi vero iste voluptates, exercitationem voluptate cum id quo rem placeat nemo.</div>
    
         <div class="flex3">
             <div class="flex4">
                 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio, cum.
             </div>
             <div class="flex5">
                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro, nostrum.
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

```css
.flex {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex1,
.flex2 {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.flex3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="flex1">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae alias dolorum cum sunt necessitatibus facere eveniet corrupti fugit fuga excepturi.</div>
    <div class="flex2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Commodi vero iste voluptates, exercitationem voluptate cum id quo rem placeat nemo.</div>
    <div class="flex3">
      <div class="flex4">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio, cum.
      </div>
      <div class="flex5">
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro, nostrum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a flex container inside the flex container I am trying to show another flex item which is placed row wise and but its justify-space between is not working. I have provided the code for the same .

Comment: Can you please draw or sketch the layout how it should be displayed? @RahulSingh

Answer (score 1):

Flex items are only as wide as their content by default, if `align-items` is something other than the default `stretch`. You need to give `flex3` a width, presumably 100%.

```css
.flex {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex1,
.flex2 {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.flex3 {
  width: 100%; /* <=== */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex1">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae alias dolorum cum sunt necessitatibus facere eveniet corrupti fugit fuga excepturi.
  </div>
  <div class="flex2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Commodi vero iste voluptates, exercitationem voluptate cum id quo rem placeat nemo.
  </div>
  <div class="flex3">
    <div class="flex4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio, cum.
    </div>
    <div class="flex5">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro, nostrum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```